# Semantics rules? A classification challenge

Tags: classification, data-imputation

Suppose we make interviews on a large number of households in which we ask, among other things, the sex and age of the individuals living in the household, and also who among these individuals is the head of the household (HOH) according to appropriate demographic definitions.

Doing this, we would end with the age of the HOH for each interviewed household; a data which will be necessary in other phases of the survey. The sex of the HOH is not important. Unfortunately, at the end of the interviews we discover that for a substantial fraction of the households, for technical reasons, the age of the HOH is missing.

Call the subset of households for which we have complete information our "Training Set". For one of the $n$ households in this Training Set we denote its data by $(x_i,y_i)$, in which $x_i$ is a set of ordered pairs $(\mathrm{sex},\mathrm{age})$, and $y_i$ is one of the ages (the age of the pointed HOH) in the pairs belonging to $x_i$. For example, in the first two household we have
$$
x_1 = \{(\mathrm{Male},3),(\mathrm{Female},13),(\mathrm{Female},35),(\mathrm{Male},35)\} \qquad y_1 = 35 \, ; 
$$
$$
x_2 = \{(\mathrm{Male},10),(\mathrm{Female},23)\} \qquad y_2 = 23 \, .
$$
The challenge is to impute for each household of the "Test Set", formed by those households for which the $y_i$'s are missing, the age of the HOH, based on the information contained in the Training Set.

Note that this classification problem has this peculiarity that the possible values of the response is constrained by the values of the predictors, since the HOH must be one of the individuals living in the household.

We already have a reasonable imputation rule based on the data semantics: say that the age of the HOH is that of the oldest male living in the household; if there are no males pick the oldest female. For the households in the Training Set this rule gives the correct answer in 70% of the cases. We also played with simple Naïve Bayes and KNN classifiers, both of which gave us worst correct classification rates, estimated by take one out cross validations within the Training Set.

It will be a pleasure to give **50** reputation points for the description of a classifier programmable in R whose empirical performance, estimated by take one out cross validation, beats the performance of the semantics rule.

Does semantics rule in this problem? Or is it possible to create a better classifier?

Comment: more semantics idea: oldest male with the fall-back on oldest female if no male? or, oldest individual younger than say 55?

Comment: Thank you Behzad. This is the actual rule we used. My description was simplified but I will edit it.

Comment: You say that the training set only has the age of the HOH, not the identity of the HOH.  But in the first paragraph, you asked for the identity of the HOH.  Did the identity get lost somewhere, or it is also available for training?

Comment: Hi Tom, in the training set, we know everything about the HOH, because we have the ordinal of the HOH in the list of the people living in the household. In the bogus set this ordinal is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multinomial logistic regression on the identity of the HOH.  Let $h_i$ be the identity of the HOH for household $i$.  This variable ranges from 1 to the size of the household.  The model for choosing the HOH is:
$$
p(h_i=h | x_i, w) = \frac{\exp(w'x_{ih})}{\sum_{j} \exp(w'x_{ij})}
$$
where $w$ is the parameter of the model and $x_{ij}$ is the attributes of the $j$th person in the household.  If all households were the same size, then you could easily fit this model using mlogit in R.  But since they have different size, I'm not sure if this package can do it.  A simple approximation would be to fit a binary logistic regression where the training points are the differences $(x_{ih} - x_{ij})$ for all $i$ and $j$, the outcomes are always 1, and there is no bias term allowed.  Once you have estimated $w$, apply the formula above to predict the HOH of a new household.

Comment: Studying the use that will be made of the survey data, it looks like they won't need the exact age of the HOH, but only if it belongs to specific ranges like $<35, 35-54, >54$. Hence I'm thinking about also binning the ages of the people living in the household (I'll start with something like $0-4, 5-12, 13-19, 20-59, >=60$) to address the "households of different size issue" and using mlogit the way you suggested. I'll report the results here.

Comment: With all the binning and stuff, MLR performed slightly better than NB and KNN. Thank you very much, Tom!